# Histogram of the distribution of dice rolls

Tags: c++, algorithm

I saw a question on careercup, but I do not get the answer I want there. I wrote an answer myself and want your comment on my analysis of time complexity and comment on the algorithm and code. Or you could provide a better algorithm in terms of time. Thanks.

You are given d > 0 fair dice with n > 0 "sides", write an function that returns a histogram of the frequency of the result of dice rolls.

For example, for 2 dice, each with 3 sides, the results are:

```
(1, 1) -> 2
(1, 2) -> 3
(1, 3) -> 4
(2, 1) -> 3
(2, 2) -> 4
(2, 3) -> 5
(3, 1) -> 4
(3, 2) -> 5
(3, 3) -> 6
```

And the function should return:

```
2: 1
3: 2
4: 3
5: 2
6: 1
```

(my sol). The time complexity if you use a brute force depth first search is O(n^d). However, you can use the DP idea to solve this problem. For example, d=3 and n=3. You can use the result of d==1 when computing d==2:

```
d==1

num  #
1    1
2    1
3    1

d==2

first roll     second roll is 1
num  #         num  # 
1    1         2    1                  
2    1      -> 3    1
3    1         4    1

first roll     second roll is 2
num  #         num  # 
1    1         3    1                  
2    1      -> 4    1
3    1         5    1

first roll     second roll is 3
num  #         num  # 
1    1         4    1                  
2    1      -> 5    1
3    1         6    1
```

Therefore,

```
second roll
num  #
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    2
6    1
```

The time complexity of this DP algorithm is

```
SUM_i(1:d) {n*[n(d-1)-(d-1)+1]} ~ O(n^2*d^2)
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--eg. d=2, n=3, range from 2~6
```

The code is written in C++ as follows

```
vector<pair<int,long long>> diceHisto(int numSide, int numDice) {
int n = numSide*numDice;
vector<long long> cur(n+1,0), nxt(n+1,0);
for(int i=1; i<=numSide; i++) cur[i]=1;

for(int i=2; i<=numDice; i++) { 
    int start = i-1, end = (i-1)*numSide; // range of previous sum of rolls
    //cout<<"start="<<start<<"   end="<<end<<endl;
    for(int j=1; j<=numSide; j++) {
        for(int k=start; k<=end; k++) 
            nxt[k+j] += cur[k];
    }

    swap(cur,nxt);
    for(int j=start; j<=end; j++) nxt[j]=0; 
}
vector<pair<int,long long>> result;
for(int i=numDice; i<=numSide*numDice; i++)
    result.push_back({i,cur[i]});
return result;
```

}

Comment: This should be posted to CodeReview@StackExchange.com.

Comment: Reviews of working code belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com  Good luck!

Comment: My mistake. Will post to codereview next time. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in O(n*d^2). First, note that the generating function for an n-sided dice is p(n) = x+x^2+x^3+...+x^n, and that the distribution for d throws has generating function p(n)^d. Representing the polynomials as arrays, you need O(nd) coefficients, and multiplying by p(n) can be done in a single pass in O(nd) time by keeping a rolling sum.

Here's some python code that implements this. It has one non-obvious optimisation: it throws out a factor x from each p(n) (or equivalently, it treats the dice as having faces 0,1,2,...,n-1 rather than 1,2,3,...,n) which is why d is added back in when showing the distribution.

```
def dice(n, d):
    r = [1] + [0] * (n-1) * d
    nr = [0] * len(r)
    for k in xrange(d):
        t = 0
        for i in xrange(len(r)):
            t += r[i]
            if i >= n:
                t -= r[i-n]
            nr[i] = t
        r, nr = nr, r
    return r

def show_dist(n, d):
    for i, k in enumerate(dice(n, d)):
        if k: print i + d, k

show_dist(6, 3)
```

The time and space complexity are easy to see: there's nested loops with d and (n-1)*d iterations so the time complexity is O(n.d^2), and there's two arrays of size O(nd) and no other allocation, so the space complexity is O(nd).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you kindly explain what does this mean and maybe give a simple example on the generating function of dice throws? "the generating function for an n-sided dice is p(n) = x+x^2+x^3+...+x^n".

Comment: The use of generating functions is a standard technique. For example, googling for "generating function dice roll" produces several useful links.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, here a simple example in Python using [the OpenTurns platform](http://www.openturns.org/).

```py
import openturns as ot
d = 2 # number of dice
n = 6 # number of sides per die

# possible values
dice_distribution = ot.UserDefined([[i] for i in range(1, n + 1)])

# create the sum distribution d times the sum
sum_distribution = sum([dice_distribution] * d)
```

That's it!

```py
print(sum_distribution)
```

will show you all the possible values and their corresponding probabilities:

```py
>>> UserDefined(
     {x = [2], p = 0.0277778},
     {x = [3], p = 0.0555556},
     {x = [4], p = 0.0833333},
     {x = [5], p = 0.111111},
     {x = [6], p = 0.138889},
     {x = [7], p = 0.166667},
     {x = [8], p = 0.138889},
     {x = [9], p = 0.111111},
     {x = [10], p = 0.0833333},
     {x = [11], p = 0.0555556},
     {x = [12], p = 0.0277778}
   )
```

You can also draw the probability distribution function:

```py
sum_distribution.drawPDF()
```

[image: Rendered image of the probability distribution function]